# Oracle OCI connections on PHP have stopped working - Apache returns ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: php, connection, oracle-call-interface

All of a sudden ( ... I know ... ) my PHP app has stopped working. When trying to establish a connection with the database I get a connection reset error.

The PHP code is:

```
 error_log("dbconn.php: db logon " . $un . "/" . $pw . "@" . $db, 0);
 $db_conn = oci_connect($un,$pw, $db); 
 error_log("dbconn.php: returned db logon ");
```

When I take the connection string and try using sqlplus it works fine.

The php_error_log logs just the first message above.

XAMPP version is 1.8.1
PHP version: 5.4

OCI:

```
oci8
OCI8 Support    enabled
Version     1.4.7
Revision    $Id: bf2eaf558b050b6d2e6d098bed6345af7e842ea4 $
Active Persistent Connections   0
Active Connections  0
Oracle Run-time Client Library Version  10.2.0.3.0
Oracle Instant Client Version   10.2
Temporary Lob support   enabled
Collections support     enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
oci8.connection_class   no value    no value
oci8.default_prefetch   100 100
oci8.events Off Off
oci8.max_persistent -1  -1
oci8.old_oci_close_semantics    Off Off
oci8.persistent_timeout -1  -1
oci8.ping_interval  60  60
oci8.privileged_connect Off Off
oci8.statement_cache_size   20  20
```

I tried debugging using

```
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

oci_internal_debug(1);
```

At the top of the script, but I cannot find any output.

like I said this was working fine for over a year.

I have tried with different databases and even tried on a completely different server with an untouched LAMPP install and I got the same result there too.

Further to the above, I found this in the Windows Event Viewer:

```
Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.4.2.0, time stamp: 0x4fafa3e6
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18229, time stamp: 0x51fb1072
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x000ce753
Faulting process id: 0x1d50
Faulting application start time: 0x01ceeaa5eef4ce6c
Faulting application path: C:\DevTools\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 2d3c2499-5699-11e3-86d7-005056c00008
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a backup of the xampp folder structure. I recopied the php folder from the backup to the xampp folder and it started working again.

I have a strong feeling that some Windows update or other is to blame.